# Convert to JSON from JAVA

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

This has been cleared and worked. I'm sorry I can't save the code here because it might be taken and could be taken as copyrighted which I do not allowed! If needed help, please email me and I will help!

Answer (score 0):

According to my knowledge no need to do extra efforts for implementing the interface and override the method.
You can create JSON string from the object using below code snippet.

```
new Gson().toJson(model);
```

and if you are converting JSON string into collection object then

```
List<Model> models= new ArrayList<Model>();
Type t = new TypeToken<List<Model>>() {
                }.getType();
models= (List<Model>) new Gson().fromJson(jsonString, t);
```

Comment: Should I still keep the strings in the MovieDatabase Class or create a new class for it?